# itext 7 pdf is not showing borders of header cells when it is followed by a cell embedding a table in win7 32bit only;works on ubuntu and win10

Tags: java, windows-7, itext, border, cell

```
        cell12 = new Cell(1, 1)
                .setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER)
                .add(new Paragraph(" Amount"))
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                .setBackgroundColor(bg).setMarginRight(0)
                .setFont(f)
                .setFontSize(9).setBold().setFontColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (chck_bx.isSelected()) {
            float[] columnWidths = {3, 6, 24, 7, 7, 7, 12, 7, 12};
            table = new Table(columnWidths);
            table.setWidthPercent(100);

            Image itext = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(getClass()
                    .getResource("/images/" + "abc.png")))
                    .setWidth(5).setHeight(7);

            float[] columnWidths_small = {5, 8};
            Table table_small = new Table(columnWidths_small);
            table_small.setWidthPercent(100);
            Cell cell11_1 = new Cell(1, 2)
                    .add(new Paragraph("col1"))
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                    .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    .setBackgroundColor(bg)
                    .setFont(f)
                    .setFontSize(9).setBold().setFontColor(Color.BLACK);
            Cell cell11_1_1 = new Cell(1, 1)
                    .add(new Paragraph("subcol1"))
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                    .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    .setBackgroundColor(bg)
                    .setFont(f)
                    .setFontSize(9).setBold().setFontColor(Color.BLACK);
            Cell cell11_1_2 = new Cell(1, 1)
                    .add(new Paragraph("subcol2"))
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                    .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    .setBackgroundColor(bg)
                    .setFont(f)
                    .setFontSize(9).setBold().setFontColor(Color.BLACK);

            Cell cell11_1_0 = new Cell(1, 2)
                    .add(table_small)
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                    .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    .setBackgroundColor(bg)
                    .setFont(f)
                    .setFontSize(9).setBold().setFontColor(Color.BLACK).setPadding(0).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);

            table_small.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).addCell(cell11_1).addCell(cell11_1_1).addCell(cell11_1_2);

            table.addHeaderCell(cell1)
                    .addHeaderCell(cell5)
                    .addHeaderCell(cell4)
                    .addHeaderCell(cell6)
                    .addHeaderCell(cell7)
                    .addHeaderCell(cell9)
                    .addHeaderCell(cell12)
                    .addHeaderCell(cell11_1_0);
```

The above cells 1,5,, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12 are normal cells while cell11_1_0 is special cell.
When I run the code in windows7 the bottom borders of all the normal cells are missing and I only see the bottom border of cell11_1_0. The other borders are intact.
The same java code works in Ubuntu and Windows 10

Comment: This happens only on 32 bit windows 7 and not on 64 bit win 7.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, the bottom border is not visible in win7 32 bit version generated pdf file, but when it is printed(on paper) I saw the border.
Thank you.